# What should I do about poor answers to my questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I asked a question, and quickly got an "answer" that didn't actually address the question (instead it suggested an alternate approach that the author admitted was worse than the approach I was asking for feedback on; pretty useless).

Now, when looking at the question in a list, it is hard to distinguish my question (that I'm actively watching, responding to comments, and hoping for an acceptable answer) from one that's been abandoned by the author without accepting the provided answer.

What should I do to distinguish my question?

This seems to happen to me a lot, as most of my questions are detailed and specific, and people like to do drive-by one-liner answers in hopes of picking up quick rep.

I'd really like a way to flag an answer as "this doesn't answer my question" and have it disappear from the high-level count (until edited, at which point I can review and accept or re-flag), which would provide a clear signal of "this question is still waiting for a correct answer" when looking at the one-line summary of the question.

Comment: Downvoting is the correct response. Commonly receiving answers that don't answer your question though may be a sign that your questions aren't very clear.

Comment: Useless *to you*, perhaps, but not objectively useless. There might be cases where the alternative they proposed is a better option, which legitimizes the answer. SO isn't a help desk; we don't provide *personalized* solutions. Rather, our goal is to build a library of high-quality solutions to programming problems. This answer may not be the *best* possible solution, but if it is a *reasonable* one that *sometimes* makes sense, it's still an answer that is worth having around, and it should not be deleted. If it doesn't work for you, downvote and (optionally) leave a comment explaining why.

Answer (score 10):

Honestly, if I see a question in the lists that has an answer or two, but they're not accepted, then I would tend to assume, if I assumed anything at all, that the OP hasn't received an answer they feel they can accept yet. I would imagine other users feel the same, while some may indeed assume the OP abandoned the question.

But really, there's a saying about assumptions, and it would ring true here. I wouldn't worry about this too much, the lists just give you a brief summary of the state of the question. If someone's judging your question from that list, it may well be for a different reason than the answer count.

There's nothing you can do to remove "incorrect" answers, and really there's nothing you can/need to do to "distinguish" your question in the list. The "need to" part is *more* true the newer the question is. Quick answers aren't uncommon on questions, and it's not uncommon for a quick answer to either miss the mark or need clarifying.

In the end, all you can do is comment on the answer, if you feel the need to point out the problems with it, and downvote it. In this case, I doubt you'd need to comment on the answer since you mentioned the answerer even said the answer was inferior to your intended approach.

Don't flag the answer as "Not An Answer" or for moderator attention, as it *is* an answer, or at least an attempt at one, and moderators really do not need to step in here. Moderators do not delete answers just because they're incorrect, since that's what downvotes are for and users with enough rep can vote to delete downvoted answers.

As KevinB mentions [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340890/what-should-i-do-about-poor-answers-to-my-questions#comment428388_340890), consistently receiving answers like this may indicate a problem with the clarity of your questions. Consider going over the question(s) again and perhaps getting a friend to read over it for clarity. Keep in mind that just because it makes sense to you *doesn't* necessarily mean it's clear to everyone. After all, you already have all the information about your problem.

> I'd really like a way to flag an answer as "this doesn't answer my question" and have it disappear from the high-level count (until edited, at which point I can review and accept or re-flag), which would provide a clear signal of "this question is still waiting for a correct answer" when looking at the one-line summary of the question.

Just because an answer doesn't work for you doesn't mean it won't work for someone else. For example, in your stated situation, the inferior solution might be the one someone else needs for various reasons. It could be the solution you're trying to use doesn't work with their exact situation, it could be that something about their setup prevents them from using it, etc.

This "flag" would be pretty subjective, and could even be misused by OPs who just don't like an answer, even though it's correct or best practice. Always remember that while you're getting an answer to your problem, the question and answer are *also* for future users with the same problem, and what doesn't work for you may be exactly what they need.

TL;DR: Downvote, optionally comment and point out what's wrong with the answer(s), and continue about your business. Don't worry about what people looking at your question in the lists think. If anything deters them, it might well not be the answer count. If this is a frequent occurrence, consider going over your questions for clarity, as that may be part of the issue.

Comment: Lack of clarity might be an issue, but I try to have others on my engineering team vet them before posting (though in this case, the holiday made that difficult). I like to think that it's because most of my questions are non-trivial, rather than unclear. This is a recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41456013/what-are-the-failure-cases-of-roundval-10-ndigits-vs-roundval-ndigits Here, the answer is giving me an alternate implementation when the question was about weakness in the implementation I proposed. It's not off topic, but it won't ever be an answer.

Comment: Non-triviality could be a cause as well. For your recent example, I honestly don't know enough (read: anything) about the technology to judge anything about that answer other than what your comments say. Your options there are indeed to downvote, if you haven't already, since it looks like a possible answer and therefore a Not An Answer flag won't work, or to bounty your question as stated in the other answer. Since the answer was posted before the bounty, you won't have to worry about the bounty being automatically awarded to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to downvoting, your other option is to award a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). This provides more visibility by making your question appear under the "featured" tab for questions.

> If you’ve asked a good question, edited it with status and progress updates, and still are not receiving answers, you can draw attention to your question by placing a bounty on it.