# Should I also flag a poor answer to a poor question?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, moderation

I found a low quality question with lack of the details, so I marked it with a relevant flag. Then, I noticed an answer for it, also with a poor quality. Should I flag it as well, if the post are going to be closed (probably)?

Related meta questions, but not an applicable answer:

- *[What should I do about poor answers to my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340890/what-should-i-do-about-poor-answers-to-my-questions)*
- *[Should one answer terribly poor questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293931/should-one-answer-terribly-poor-questions)*

Comment: If it could possibly be seen as an attempt at an answer (and isn't link-only), then it's not flaggable, even if the answer is extremely poor or wrong.

Comment: You should downvote posts of low quality. If there is a flag that is applicable, flag the post as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should flag every post based on its own content and not the content of other posts. In your case, the answer should be flagged only if the content of the post itself is deserving of a flag. If the answer is just poor quality it would be best to downvote and move on.

Answer (score 4):

You should flag an answer if it's eligible to be flagged. For example an answer which is wrong is not eligible to be flagged and should be downvoted.Check the discussion in [*When do I flag, and which flag do I use?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89707/when-do-i-flag-and-which-flag-do-i-use).

Raising wrong flag might lead to flags being rejected by moderators and when it reaches to certain number you might get flag banned. So choose the right flag very carefully specially the "Very Low Quality" one because *quality* is subjective.